# Trying to only return distinct ID entries from a table where all values of a certain column must be matched

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-division

So the Situation is that I have 3 Tables, 2 of which are "helper" tables while the other one is the main table I'm trying to get distinct IDs out of:

Main Table dbo.recipes has columns ID, Name and some others such as:

```
ID  NAME
5   Veggie Cassola
6   Mozzarella Penne
7   Wiener Schnitzel with Fries
8   Grilled Salmon with Rice
9   Greek style Salad
```

The helpers are dbo.stock:

```
ID_USER     ID_INGREDIENT
1           225
1           585
1           607
1           643
1           763
1           874
1           937
1           959
1           960
2           225
2           246
2           331
2           363
2           511
2           585
```

and dbo.content:

```
ID_INGREDIENT   ID_RECIPE
98              5
196             5
333             5
607             5
608             5
613             5
627             5
643             5
763             5
874             5
951             5
956             5
225             6
585             6
607             6
```

Basically the dbo.stock is the inventory of ingredients that the user has hence user id and ingredient id.
The dbo.content is the ingredients needed to make a certain dish.

What I want to query is ONLY recipes that the user actually has the ingredients for, so that means that all the recipes which have ALL their ingredients matched (to a certain user) should be returned. The code that I have at  the moment for my procedure is as follows:

```sql
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[recipe]
    WHERE [recipe].[id] NOT IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT [content].[id_recipe] FROM [dbo].[content]
        WHERE [content].[id_ingredient] NOT IN
            (SELECT [stock].[id_ingredient] FROM [dbo].[stock]
                WHERE [stock].[id_user] = @userID))
```

which works, but I doubt this is the best way to achieve this. Is there a better way to reach the same?

MS SQL Server Express 2019

Comment: Just wait until you add the complexity of whether they have _enough_ of a certain ingredient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you want to find all the recipes where there isn't an ingredient in content that is not in stock. It's not the way you think about it in English, but it leads to this if you think about it that way in SQL:

```
DECLARE @userID int = 1;

SELECT ID, NAME
FROM dbo.recipe AS r
WHERE NOT EXISTS
( 
  SELECT id_ingredient FROM dbo.content WHERE id_recipe = r.ID
  EXCEPT
  SELECT id_ingredient FROM dbo.stock WHERE id_user = @userID
);
```

However, this query is more along the lines of yours, just without the expensive `DISTINCT`s found in both of the above plans ([`EXCEPT` is sneaky like that](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)), so is probably the best option:

```
DECLARE @userID int = 1;

SELECT ID, NAME
FROM dbo.recipe AS r
WHERE NOT EXISTS
( 
  SELECT 1 FROM dbo.content AS c
  WHERE id_recipe = r.ID AND NOT EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.stock 
    WHERE id_ingredient = c.id_ingredient
      AND id_user = @userID
  )
);
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ccefcb3f8555de14e2c832c6450d3905)

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much.
I was trying so long yesterday to get this working with NOT EXISTS and EXCEPT but just could not wrap my head around saving the query as a view temporarily with "AS".

Now I finally understand how to structure this syntax, all the googling and reading yesterday simply didn't work out. Thank you again so much.

Answer (score 1):

**This is a classic [*Relational Division With Remainder*](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) question.**

@AaronBertrand has given you a couple good solutions. Here is another one that is often used.

```sql
DECLARE @userID int = 1;

SELECT
  r.Id,
  r.Name
FROM dbo.recipe AS r
JOIN dbo.content AS c ON c.id_recipe = r.ID
LEFT JOIN dbo.stock AS s ON s.id_ingredient = c.id_ingredient
    AND s.id_user = @userID
GROUP BY
  r.Id,
  r.Name
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(s.id_ingredient);
```

This will join everything together (left-joining the `stock`), group by the `recipe` and return only those groupings that have the same number of rows as there are non-null `stock` rows. In other words, every `content` must match, and there must be at least one `content`.

There is a semantic difference: if you wanted also all `recipes` which have *no* `content, you can change it slightly.

```sql
DECLARE @userID int = 1;

SELECT
  r.Id,
  r.Name
FROM dbo.recipe AS r
LEFT JOIN dbo.content AS c ON c.id_recipe = r.ID
LEFT JOIN dbo.stock AS s ON s.id_ingredient = c.id_ingredient
    AND s.id_user = @userID
GROUP BY
  r.Id,
  r.Name
HAVING COUNT(c.id_recipe) = COUNT(s.id_ingredient);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=84817ce8baa728d18c59128d4e29f834)